# Proper response to "con permiso"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, cortesía

When someone says *con permiso*, for example when squeezing through a crowd, what is the appropriate response? For example, in English we might say something like "sorry" or "go ahead."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spain I've used or heard being used the following:

- Por supuesto
- Pasa / Pase
- Tranquilo
- Claro
- Sin problema

I'm sure there's more, but those are very common.

Answer (score 6):

In Mexico we use:

- Pase usted.
- Adelante.
- Pásele. (which sounds more informal)

Comment: "Siga" but also very informal

Comment: Sometimes I say: "Sí, claro" indicating with my hands he can go ahead, or "Sí, perdone/disculpe" if it was my fault because I was blocking his way and I could have avoided it.

Comment: Siga is a good one!

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico, another common response to "con permiso" is "propio". Literally, it signifies, "you own/you have permission" to pass by.

Comment: I agree completely with adding "Propio" to the list of responses commonly found in Mexico that was contributed earlier by Alfredo.  In fact, as I was reading Alfredo's post I was thinking, Yes, those are good, but I better add "Propio." // as for the usage, there isn't much to say.  Someone says, "Con permiso," and you say, "Propio."  Just like in Alfredo's answer.

Comment: I heard “propio” in Guatemala as well!